# Configure HTML Minification in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, minify, bundling-and-minification

I am implementing minification for my project. I have made changes as per [documentation](https://webmarkupmin.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebMarkupMin%200.9.2).

Here is my updated web.config file:

```
<webMarkupMin xmlns="http://tempuri.org/WebMarkupMin.Configuration.xsd">
<core>
  <html whitespaceMinificationMode="Medium" removeHtmlComments="true"
     removeHtmlCommentsFromScriptsAndStyles="true"
     removeCdataSectionsFromScriptsAndStyles="true"
     useShortDoctype="true" useMetaCharsetTag="true"
     emptyTagRenderMode="NoSlash" removeOptionalEndTags="true"
     removeTagsWithoutContent="false" collapseBooleanAttributes="true"
     removeEmptyAttributes="true" attributeQuotesRemovalMode="Html5"
     removeRedundantAttributes="true"
     removeJsTypeAttributes="true" removeCssTypeAttributes="true"
     removeHttpProtocolFromAttributes="false"
     removeHttpsProtocolFromAttributes="false"
     removeJsProtocolFromAttributes="true"
     minifyEmbeddedCssCode="true" minifyInlineCssCode="true"
     minifyEmbeddedJsCode="true" minifyInlineJsCode="true"
     processableScriptTypeList="" minifyKnockoutBindingExpressions="false"
     minifyAngularBindingExpressions="false" customAngularDirectiveList="" />
  <css defaultMinifier="KristensenCssMinifier">
    <minifiers>
      <add name="NullCssMinifier" displayName="Null CSS Minifier"
         type="WebMarkupMin.Core.Minifiers.NullCssMinifier, WebMarkupMin.Core" />
      <add name="KristensenCssMinifier"
         displayName="Mads Kristensen's CSS minifier"
         type="WebMarkupMin.Core.Minifiers.KristensenCssMinifier, WebMarkupMin.Core" />

    </minifiers>
  </css>
  <js>
    <minifiers>
      <add name="NullJsMinifier" displayName="Null JS Minifier" type="WebMarkupMin.Core.Minifiers.NullJsMinifier, WebMarkupMin.Core" />
      <add name="CrockfordJsMinifier" displayName="Douglas Crockford's JS Minifier" type="WebMarkupMin.Core.Minifiers.CrockfordJsMinifier, WebMarkupMin.Core" />
    </minifiers>
  </js>
  <logging>
    <loggers>
      <add name="NullLogger" displayName="Null Logger" type="WebMarkupMin.Core.Loggers.NullLogger, WebMarkupMin.Core" />
      <add name="ThrowExceptionLogger" displayName="Throw exception logger" type="WebMarkupMin.Core.Loggers.ThrowExceptionLogger, WebMarkupMin.Core" />
    </loggers>
  </logging>

</core>
```

and Action method seems like this:

```
 [MinifyHtmlAttribute]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

This is works fine on my home page. But what if I want to add HTML minifier in all pages of my site? Is there anything else to implement HTML minifier in whole of my project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although `MinifyHtmlAttribute` inherits from `ActionFilterAttribute` it apparently does not function as a global action filter. So, your only option is to explicitly add `[MinifyHtmlAttribute]` to each one of the action methods you wish to minify.

That said, the project is open source so it is possible you could invent your own way to configure it that works similar to the `[AuthorizeAttribute]` and `[AllowAnnonymousAttribute]` in MVC.

Comment: Can you please tell me where I need to place this code in my MVC project?

Comment: The above is the code that comes in the default MVC template. The code in your application may differ. The only thing that matters is that you register the filter within the `Application_Start()` method, but your application may already have a place to do so.

Comment: @NightOwI888: I am getting "Filtering is not allowed." error in Index.cshtml view page.

Answer (score 0):

Now in the [WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Mvc/) module from the [WebMarkupMin version 2.X](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin) you can apply the action filters at the level of whole application (see [related section](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/wiki/WebMarkupMin:-ASP.NET-4.X-MVC) of the documentation).